# Could not find screenshot option on Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using Firefox Quantum 63.0.3 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04. I could not find the "Take a Screenshot" button on the address bar. But I remember it was there and I have used it once or twice. 
Here's what it looks like now:
[image: No take screenshot button]

Comment: Open `about:config` and find `extensions.screenshots.disabled` (on some versions, it's called `extensions.screenshots.system-disabled`).  See if that's set to true.  If so, double-click on it and set it to false.  Let me know whether that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox Screenshots icon is now here on my Firefox version 63 :

[image]

I suggest to see if your version is 63. If it is, then your case might be
described in the
[Firefox Screenshots page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots):

> Don't see Screenshots? We are still testing this feature so not everyone will see it.

You will then need to wait patiently for an update to Firefox for your operating
system that will enable this feature.